# how to only to choose a form:select value using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp-tags

I have found different answers to similar questions, but not to this one.

I want  to make sure that the user selects something from a dropdown list, like in my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Provincia:</label> 
    <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
    <div>
        <form:select path="provincia" id="provincia" name="provincia">
        <form:option value="" label="Seleccionar Provincia" />
        <form:options items="${provincia}" value="${provincia.id_provincia}" selected="${selected}"></form:options>
        </form:select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I would like it to be in the browser, not in the server.**

PD: When I use required in HTML (select name="somename" required) or (class="required"), it doesnot work.
- The Javascript solutions that I have found does not work either.

Thanks

Comment: How does it get rendered in your browser?

Comment: To prove that `required` attribute does work https://jsfiddle.net/915mL713/

Comment: `$('#provincia')` should get your select use `#` for ids and `.` for classes

Comment: Thanks Morpheus. It might work with a normal select, but it does not work with a form:select (tag library). Can you get the same with the  form:select (tag library)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I am currently using for one of my projects. SupplierType is a dropdown and so is SupplierPremium, however; that dropdown is conditionally required. Keep an eye on your console window to ensure JQueryValidation is properly installed.

```
        //Start Validation
        $("#AddSupplier").validate({
            errorClass: 'errors',
            rules: {
                SupplierName: {
                    required: true,
                    email: false
                },
                SupplierType: {
                    required: true
                },
                SupplierPremium: {
                    required: function (element) { return $("#SupplierType").val() == 'Auction'; }
        }

            },
            messages: {
                SupplierType: { required: "Please select a supplier type" }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the JQuery validation plugin. This is completely client side, user friendly and can be used for a variety of different situations. [Jquery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: this should be a comment rather than an answer :)(

Comment: Sorry, but I do not find one example done with a Dropdown list (and I could not make it work with it). Do you have one? Thanks